# not getting how to go on next page , given link in anchor tag is opening something else using python beautifulsoup

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

want to go to the next page to scrape each company details, not getting how to go on next page as the link in not changing.

i tried the link given in anchor tag.the code is given below.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import requests

r = requests.get('http://gidclodhika.com/company-lists/Automobile--Spares--and--Accessories/16')

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,'lxml')

links = soup.find('ul',{"id":"pagination"})

for count in range(1,4):
    for link in links.find_all('a',{"id":count}):
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just need to grab the href, then use requests to get that next page.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

r = requests.get('http://gidclodhika.com/company-lists/Automobile--Spares--and--Accessories/16')

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,'lxml')


query_str_param = '?p=Automobile--Spares--and--Accessories&'
links = soup.find('ul',{"id":"pagination"})

for count in range(1,4):
    for link in links.find_all('a',{"id":count}):
        link_url = link['href']

        link_url = link_url.split('?')
        link_url.insert( 1, query_str_param)
        link_url = ''.join(link_url)
        r = requests.get(link_url)
        print (link_url)
```

Comment: getting the links but not getting the next page , from link_url's the next page opening is very different having only one name. Not getting the proper next page , which we got from clicking on pagination 2 and 3.

Comment: @NiteshRao, I see now. I updated my code in the solution. Give that a try

Comment: I  tried to get the links of all companies on all 3 pages but it is giving only page 1 companies links. I also used for loop but it is working.